# SWT DLL Recompilation on windows

Tags: c, eclipse, windows, dll, swt

I have an eclipse-based rich client application that in some case crashes. Getting the JVM dump, the error shown is a 0xC0000005 (invalid access) into a swt dll.

```
Current thread (0x02b58400):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5032, stack(0x00090000,0x00190000)]
siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xfeeefef6
[...]

Stack: [0x00090000,0x00190000],  sp=0x0018dd78,  free space=1015k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native  code)
C  [swt-win32-3659.dll+0x1131f]  Java_org_eclipse_swt_internal_win32_OS_VtblCall__II+0xb
J  org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.IUnknown.Release()I
j  org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleControlSite.releaseObjectInterfaces()V+9
j  org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite.onDispose(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+83
```

I was not able to understand why this crashes, so I got the source code of the SWT dll from the org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.source_3.6.3.v3659f plugin and tried to build it.

When I try to launch the build i get this error

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 7.10.3077
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
cl -O1 -DNDEBUG -c -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -nologo -D_X86_=1-DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -W3 -D_WINNT -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500-D_WIN32_IE=0x0500 -DWINVER=0x0500  -D_MT -MTd   -DSWT_VERSION=3659  -DUSE_ASSEMBLER  /I"S:\swt-builddir\ibm-java2-sdk-50-win-i386\include" /I"S:\swt-builddir\ibm-java2-sdk-50-win-i386\include\win32" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Vc7\PlatformSDK\Include" /I. os.c
    os.c
c:\temp\secnew\SWT_3659\os_structs.h(100) : error C2143: syntax error : missing    '{' before '*'
c:\temp\secnew\SWT_3659\os_structs.h(100) : error C2143: syntax error : missing    ')' before '*'
c:\temp\secnew\SWT_3659\os_structs.h(100) : error C2081: 'BUTTON_IMAGELIST' : name in formal parameter list illegal
```

I changed the build.bat using the correct path for VS and JRE, but nothing worked. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: I downloaded a similar version `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.source_3.6.1.v3655c.jar.zip` and i was able to compile it for 64bit (w some tweeks) using VS2010. I noticed that you are using (ancient) VS2003. However when compiling a dll that will be loaded in an app caution should be used because they should use the same C (VC) runtime. If they don't, the program could crash in some situations (may be your case too). Look for `jvm.dll`in your `JAVA_HOME` and load it in [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com). In the left _TreView_ look for `MSVCR*.DLL` and please post the result.

Comment: I'm using JRE 1.7.0.25 (oracle standard), did not find the jvm.dll but the java.dll, which depends from MSVCRT100.DLL, then I checked the dependencies of the swt.win32.3659.dll and it depends only from MSVC.DLL. I don't remember if this difference is relatad to different runtime or to different releases of MSVCRT needed. At this moment my suspicion is that there are some issues in using SWT 3659 and jre 1.7, what is your opinion ? Thanks a lot